# Using Double Colon :: and the Hotkey command in the same script breaks one

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

I have the oddest behavior happening in a script.  In the following MWE, the `Hotkey F2` declaration doesn't work as long as the `F1` line is there.  If I comment out line 2, then the `F2` hotkey works just fine.

```
#SingleInstance, Force
F1::MsgBox You pressed F1
Hotkey F2, Alone
return

Alone:
MsgBox You pressed F2.
return
```

Is there an interaction between the double colon notation and the "Hotkey" command that causes this?  Is there a way around this?

Of course this is part of a larger script with several different hotkeys defined.  Double colon notation is used for most hotkeys in the code, but I think I have to use the Hotkey command for dynamic keys (say one defined via an ini file).  This code is a part of a larger code set with static hotkeys (using double colon notation) and I can't change that part of the code.

I am running Autohotkey v1.1.25.02 on Windows Enterprise 1909 (OS Build 18363.720)

Note: I have noticed that if I put the double colon declarations after the `Hotkey` command (i.e. reordered lines 2 and 3) it seems to work.  I don't know if that is an option.  There is hundreds of lines of code in the original script.  I'd still like to know what is happening to cause the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a one-liner hotkey `F1`.
Code execution won't continue to the lines below.

Here's the syntax you're looking for:

```
#SingleInstance, Force

F1::
    MsgBox, You pressed F1
    Hotkey, F2, Alone
return

Alone:
    MsgBox, You pressed F2.
return
```

Comment: Actually, the F1 and F2 hotkeys are meant to be independent hotkeys.    I wouldn't want to put the `Hotkey, F2, Alone` inside the process called by F1.  Perhaps adding that first `return` line was a not the right move, but I've noticed that if I don't, the script runs the subprocess "Alone" on script startup.   I'll try making the F1 hotkey a multiliner and see if that fixes it.

Comment: In that case, the `return` doesn't do anything and you should have the `Hotkey` command in the [auto execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto). When you initially run the script, code execution stops at the first hotkey label that is encountered. The `Hotkey` command was never executed in your code. And yes, the auto-execution section will go into your labels unless you stop the code execution before them. (Side note, labels are legacy, use functions)

Comment: Okay, I'm confused.  The `Hotkey` command doesn't get executed because it's not in the autoexecute section, which ends at the hotkey declaration on line 2.  However, the execution continues through the label below (sans the `return` on line 4)?  These seem to contradict each other.   Sorry about my questions, my only formal language training was in LaTeX. The label was used b/c it was the simplest example in the [Hotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm) command documentation.  It's not absolutely necessary to this.

Comment: Nono, in this particular case the auto-execute section indeed doesn't go to the label, because code execution is stopped before it by the hotkey label (and also the `return`). In your first comment you just said how code inside labels was getting executed at times when you didn't want it to happen, so I just mentioned that cause in those cases is code execution *bleeding* into the labels.